# Redirect entire folder and contents using 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to do a simple 301 redirect for the following URLs:

**From:**

```
http://example.com/blog/category/*
http://example.com/blog/tag/*
```

**To:**

```
http://example.com/category/*
http://example.com/tag/*
```

Where the `*` character represents any given category or tag that could possibly be requested.

So I need to have a wildcard in place so that whenever any category or tag is requested, it redirects to the URL *without* the `blog` folder.

Is there any way to achieve this with a 301 redirect in my `.htaccess` file?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` would be better for its regex capabilities. Use this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(category|tag)/(.*)$ /$1/$2
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get that to work. Does anything look wrong in my `.htaccess` file? http://pastebin.com/YgjWTWDf (note that all of my other redirects are working properly)

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.timpeter.com/blog/category/leadership/ should be redirecting to http://www.timpeter.com/category/leadership/

Comment: Ah my mistake, I had leading slash missing in my answer. Fixed it now and it should work.